# Configuration for Java EE 5.0

Tags: jsp, servlets, java-ee-5

I want to know the JSP and Servlet (exact) version used in the Java EE 5.0 version. I have just added the web-app_2_5.xsd in the `web.xml` file. Want to check the JAR files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java EE 5.0 ships with Servlet 2.5 and JSP 2.1. You should not have the need to modify any JAR files in an existing Java EE environment. To the point, you need to ensure that the whole environment at its own supports it. A proper environment would be a Servlet 2.5 capable container/server, for example [Tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org), [Oracle Glassfish 2](http://glassfish.java.net), [JBoss AS 5](http://jboss.org/jbossas). They are downloadable at their own homepages.

You also need to ensure that your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and the `JRE/lib` and `JRE/lib/ext` do not contain any servletcontainer-specific libraries like `jsp-api.jar`, `servlet-api.jar`, etcetera, which originated in an older versioned servletcontainer. They may collide with the libraries of the real servletcontainer and result in `NoClassDefFoundError`, `AbstractMethodError` exceptions and like that.